# Changing Taskbar Icon

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I am working on a WinUI 3 app, and I have an icon for the taskbar, but now I'm looking to switch it to a different one.

I tried following [the accepted answer to this question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/822928/app-icon-windows-app-sdk), but I couldn't get it to work. I also tried to instead follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/iconography/visual-studio-asset-generation) to change the icon where there is supposed to be a [Manifest Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/vsix-manifest-designer?view=vs-2022), but whenever I double-click on the `Package.appxmanifest` file, it just opens the XAML view and I'm not sure where to go from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not sure which code I can add to help explain my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whenever I double-click on the Package.appxmanifest file, it just opens the XAML

I think this is a non-packaged app. Can you try this in `MainWindow`?

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Activated += MainWindow_Activated;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        WindowId windowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
        AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
        appWindow.SetIcon(@"Assets\red.ico");
    }
}
```

You might need to install the **Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32** NuGet package. It's still in preview so don't forget to check "Include prerelease".

Comment: This worked great! I'm just wondering why? I originally made my app as a packaged app, and it made a bunch of images in my `Assets` folder with the old icon, if the app is now unpackaged, does that mean that all these images are now no longer needed?

Comment: If find *<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>* in your app csproj file, then your app is unpackaged. AFAIK, this line is never added automatically. You must have added it manually.